# Change text numbers based on user input

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to change some text numbers based on what the user inputs into a text input.

See mock up below:

[image]

So when the user types in the per hour box I want the per annum figure to change.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Come on guys, when you down vote someone give them the courtesy of saying why. It's a valid question, even if it is elementary, and a valid answer was provided by one of the more predominant members of the site.

Comment: Thanks, there's some massively sarcastic people on here and there's no need for it when genuine people like me need some help!

Comment: @Rob, I think the sarcasm would decrease if you showed that you've actually tried to write a solution yourself rather than just come on to SO and ask for an answer straight off. Asking without showing previous attempts is like copy/pasting from a "JavaScript Cookbook" and it will no really increase your abilities. Don't forget that everyone helping on SO is doing it voluntarily so don't abuse people's knowledge and expect them to do your job for you

Comment: @Rob - Yes, there _are_ some sarcastic people around, and I agree with Ryan that down-votes should be explained, but I don't think Tomalak's answer was sarcastic. He told you what you needed to know to implement your requirement. If you need more detail I'd suggest rather than hoping for a fully coded solution to this specific problem you should read through some introductory JavaScript tutorials on coding for events and then you'll be able to handle much more complicated problems than this without help.

Comment: @Ryan: The question shows zero research effort. Hover your mouse cursor over the downvote button for some example downvote reasons.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, fair enough to downvote for that reason but by not making it clear to the person asking doesn't help that person in the future. I have been on SO for over 6-months and didn't know about hovering over the downvote button for example. That isn't to say I don't agree with what you're saying, I do believe that Rob should have done a bit of homework first on this question but I don't see a problem in providing direction when someone needs it at the same time

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree Tomalak's answer isn't sarcastic, I also don't believe Rob was asking for a fully coded answer, to me it sounds like 'where should I start?' but that's just my reading of it

Comment: @Ryan: I'm sure your tune will change when you deal with hundreds of these weekly. :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal if you are frustrated with questions that you don't believe are complete then why don't you simply not answer then and leave it for someone else??

Comment: @Ryan: You might just as well ask why SO moderators exist, or why we bother with policemen: if you don't like crime, just stay away from criminals, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Yes, it is possible.

Set a handler on a textbox for the `change` event, then multiply the textbox's value by the required amount, and finally store the new value in the target `span` or `div` (possibly using their `.innerHTML` property).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Would it be possible to see a code example?

Comment: @Rob: I'd like to see some coding attempts from you first. At least, without knowing your markup anything I give you would need recreating anyway. But I have given you enough keywords to do the the requisite research and put the pieces together.